# How to call model's function from view's script in Laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a countdown timer in my view's script block. Edit.blade.php:

```
<div class='bottom_timer_block'>
    <span class="bottime_title">Subscription period</span>
    <span><b>End date:</b> {{ $paid_till }}</span>
    <span>
        <b>Countdown timer: </b>
        <span id="demo"></span>
            <script>
                var countDownDate = new Date('{{ $paid_till }}').getTime();                         
                var x = setInterval(function() {
                // Get todays date and time
                var now = new Date().getTime();

                // Find the distance between now an the count down date
                var distance = countDownDate - now;

                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // Display the result in the element with id="demo" 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                // If the count down is finished, write some text 
                if (distance < 0) {                                         
                    $.post("/ajax/update-payment", {id:$user->id} ).done(function( data ) {                                                                                           
                    });

                    clearInterval(x);                                           
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
                }
                }, 1000);
            </script>
```

When the counter reaches it's limit. It should call updatePayment function located in my "User" model. My AjaxController:

```
function updatePayment($id = 0){        
    $user = User::where('id', $id);
    $user->is_paid = 0;
    $user->paid_date = null;
    $user->paid_till = null;
    $user->save();
}
```

But instead of that I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >" error. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are passing a php variable directly to javascript :

```
{id:$user->id}
```

however, another issue is that curly braces has special meaning in blade template engine, so you should pass it as follows:

```
{id: '{{ $user->id }}' }
```